# firing a event on text input in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sokeord" onkeyup="Validate(this)" 
onvalidated="Ajax( 'GET', { view : '/search/all/', table : 'company', keyword : this.value } , Show, 'result')">
```

I have the above element on my page.

The `onkeyup` event fires as expected and runs the function `Validate`. The function `Validate` (as you probably guessed) validates the input based on some parameters and, if the validation evaluates to `true`, `Validate` tries to fire the event `onvalidated` on the input element 'sokeord', but the `onvalidated` event does not fire. I have tried `$(element).trigger("onvalidated");`

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onvalidated` is not a valid Event, so you need to call your `ajax` somewhere else if you want it to be executed.

One way to do it, is adding your `ajax` call to the `Validate` function instead, so when the validation takes place (and succeeds) it will make `ajax` call.

So you could do something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="sokeord" onkeyup="Validate(this)">

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function Validate(element) {
      // Your validation code
      // Set a variable to true/false (e.g `var valid = ...`)

      if(valid) {
        $.ajax({
          // your ajax call
        });
      }
  });
</script>
```